# Constructing Matrix (Rotation, Reflection)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Construct the matrix corresponding to a rotation of 90 degrees about the y-axis together with a reflection about the (x,z) plane.

Reviewing Linear Algebra and seem to have forgotten some stuff.  Not sure what to do with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is in 3-space and your rotation is CCW. We can figure out the matrix for this transformation by seeing where it sends the standard basis vectors. $[1, 0, 0]^T$ gets rotated to $[0, 1, 0]^T$ then reflected to $[0, -1, 0]^T$. $[0, 1, 0]^T$ gets rotated to $[-1, 0, 0]^T$ and it is fixed by the reflection since it's on the x-axis. $[0, 0, 1]^T$ is fixed by the rotation and also by the reflection. Put these transformed basis vectors next to each other and you have your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what the images are of each of the 3 standard unit vectors.
Put them next to each other in a matrix... and presto! :)